# JavaScript check upload type

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ecmascript-6, upload

I have a simple form to upload a video. I am doing a check on the type as follows:

```
if ($fileSelected.type === 'video/mp4' || $fileSelected.type === 'video/ogg' || $fileSelected.type === 'video/webm' || $fileSelected.type === 'video/avi') {}
```

I wanted to know if there is perhaps a better, neater way or shorthand way of doing the above? Maybe using new ES6 syntax & methods?

All help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have an array with all the supported types and check with [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) if a specific one is in it:

```
const acceptedTypes = ['video/mp4', 'video/ogg', 'video/webm', 'video/avi'];

if (acceptedTypes.indexOf($fileSelected.type) !== -1) {
    ...
}
```

If support is not an issue, you could also use [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), but you need a polyfill for IE and older versions of other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Put valid mime types into an array, then check if the uploaded file's mime type exists in the array:

```
const mimeTypes = ['video/mp4', 'video/webm', 'video/avi', 'video/ogg'] 

if ( mimeTypes.includes( $fileSelected.type ) ){
  // continue 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @adam-azad :) This also worked